# Deploy to Amazon S3 on Appveyor

Tags: deployment, amazon-s3, appveyor

I am trying to deploy artifacts from AppVeyor into an Amazon S3 Bucket. However, whenever AppVeyor runs, it does not come up with any kind of deployment message and does not deploy to the bucket. What would likely be the cause of this?
I have included a bit from my .yml file

```
artifacts:
  - path: <launcher location>
    name: <filename>
    type: zip

deploy:
  - provider: S3
    access_key_id:  <id>
    secret_access_key:
      secure: <key>
    bucket: <bucket name>
    region: eu-west-1
    artifact: <filename>.zip
    set_public: true
```

and a bit from my log

```
[00:01:40] Everything is Ok
[00:01:40] appveyor PushArtifact launcher.zip
[00:01:41] Packaging artifacts...
[00:01:41] OK
[00:01:41] Build success
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably it was pull request (PR) build. Deployment is disabled during PR builds.